# 'No property or field 'GoodName' exists in type 'GoodDomain'' for server side processing in jquery datatable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, datatables

I'm using `jquery datatable` for showing my data.I want to use server side proccesing in jquery datatable using asp.net mvc but I've a problem with it.I have a class that it hasn't GoodName property but I want to sort my table based on `GoodName` property.but i've got error `'No property or field 'GoodName' exists in type 'GoodDomain'` I know that `GoodName` doesn't exist in `GoodDomian` but i can access `GoodName` property by navigation property `Good.GooName` but I can't use it in this statement.because I've used `Linq.Dynamic`

```
 query = query.OrderBy(orderByString == string.Empty ? "GoodName asc + " : orderByString);
```

---

```
   public ActionResult LoadData([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestModel)
    {
        IQueryable<GoodDomain> query = db.GoodDomains;
        var totalCount = query.Count();

        #region Filtering 

        // Apply filters for searching 
        if (requestModel.Search.Value != string.Empty)
        {
            var value = requestModel.Search.Value.Trim();
            query = query.Where(p =>
                                     p.Good.GoodName.Contains(value)

                               );
        }

        var filteredCount = query.Count();

        #endregion Filtering 

        #region Sorting 

        // Sorting 
        var sortedColumns = requestModel.Columns.GetSortedColumns();
        var orderByString = String.Empty;

        foreach (var column in sortedColumns)
        {
            orderByString += orderByString != String.Empty ? "," : "";
            orderByString += (column.Data) + (column.SortDirection == Column.OrderDirection.Ascendant ? " asc" : " desc");
        }

        query = query.OrderBy(orderByString == string.Empty ? "MinRage asc + " : orderByString); // I've a problem
        //query =db.GoodDomains.OrderBy( g => g.Good.GoodName)
        #endregion Sorting 


        // Paging 
        query = query.Skip(requestModel.Start).Take(requestModel.Length);


        var data = query.Select(g => new
        {
            GoodDomainID = g.GoodDomainID,
            GoodName = g.Good.GoodName,
            GoodHeadName = g.GoodHead.GoodHeadName,
            GoodFootName = g.GoodFoot.GoodFootName,
            WorkhouseName = g.Workhouse.WorkhouseName,
            MinRange = g.MinRange,
            MaxRange = g.MaxRange,

        }).ToList();

        return Json(new DataTablesResponse(requestModel.Draw, data, filteredCount, totalCount), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

---

```
 public class GoodDomain
    {
        [Key]
        public int GoodDomainID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> GoodHeadeId { get; set; }
        public virtual GoodHead GoodHead { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> GoodFootId { get; set; }
        public virtual GoodFoot GoodFoot { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> GoodId { get; set; }
        public virtual Good Good { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "نام کارگاه")]

        public Nullable<int> WorkhouseId { get; set; }

        public virtual Workhouse Workhouse { get; set; }



        public Nullable<int> MaxRange  { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> MinRange  { get; set; }



    }
```